# Issue with JSON to JAXB conversion using Jackson's ObjectMapper

Tags: json, jaxb, jersey, jackson, objectmapper

I am working on a JAX-RS project. I am facing an issue with JSON to JAXB deserialization using Jackson's ObjectMapper.

The technologies/frameworks used are -

- Jackson (FasterXML) 2.8.5
- JAXB 2.2

The issue is with all IDREF fields while deserialising JSON to JAXB.

For the below XSD fragment -

```
<xsd:attribute name="ref" type="xsd:IDREF">
</xsd:attribute>
```

JAXB's xjc tool generates the below Java code fragment in the JAXB class -

```
@XmlAttribute(name = "ref")
@XmlIDREF
@XmlSchemaType(name = "IDREF")
protected Object ref;
```

This IDREF (@XmlIDREF) annotated field is supposed to be actually having a reference to another object somewhere in the object graph of the same root JAXB object. This another object would be designated as ID (@XmlID) as in the below code fragment -

```
@XmlID
@XmlSchemaType(name = "ID")
protected String objectKey;
```

and its equivalent xsd fragment used to generate the above code is -

```
<xsd:attribute name="ObjectKey" type="xsd:ID" .....>
</xsd:attribute>
```

After the deserialization instead of the actual reference to the Java object in the 'ref' field, it has the reference to the appropriate LinkedHashMap itself which is not right. Basically since 'ref' is of 'Object' type, the Jackson's ObjectMapper is setting it as-is without introspecting the @XmlIDREF annotation. JAXB's unmarshaller handles this correctly while deserializing from XML to JAXB by assigning the reference to the original (ID) object. But Jackson's ObjectMapper does not seem to be resolving this while deserializing from JSON to JAXB.

I already tried registering JaxbAnnotationIntrospector in Jackson's ObjectMapper but the only difference is, the IDREF fields have the String value instead of the LinkedHashMap.

I am not sure if I am missing something.

Any solution will be extremely helpful.

Comment: In my setting, the full object is marshalled at `ref`. I am also searching for the unmarshalling.

Comment: Jackson issue https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-base/issues/46#issuecomment-393038597] seems to be related.

Answer (score 1):

This below opensource git repo solves this issue - 
[jaxb-id-resolver](https://github.com/frankjjava/jaxb-id-resolver)

After deserializing from JSON to JAXB objects, invoke the resolve() method on JaxbIdRefResolverImpl class.